# Optimal database design to store array of options in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have two sets of 'Users' - Customers and Suppliers.

A supplier can select a group of 'areas' they choose to service. There are currently 8 areas, ie: A1, A2, B2, Etc. When a customer makes an enquiry I will need to find suppliers who match the area that the customer has specified.

I'm new to database design and I'm wondering if there is an optimal way to store the 'areas' chosen by the supplier under the circumstances above.

For example, do I add an extra column to the user database which holds an array of areas or do I set up another separate table with a belongs_to relationship with the users?

If it helps, I am using Ruby Rails and have one model for all types of 'users'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation, then you have 3 Tables:
 1. users
 2. areas
 3. areas_users
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference

Comment: Perfect! Then I guess you just use a boolean value for each column.